# Are classes indexed in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

In past web development I have always tried to descend from an id when constructing a selector in javascript, previously in jQuery and more recently using document.querySelector()/.querySelectorAll().  This was for performance reasons. I was following advice in posts like this (http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#descend-from-id).

For example:

```
$('#new-address-form input.address')
```

could be significantly faster than

```
$('.address')
```

Even when there was only one element on the page with a class of address. If there were a lot of different classes in the DOM, this could be *a lot* faster in some browsers (I'm looking at you IE<8).

But, experientially, it seems today that this is no longer the case. Can anyone point me to some documentation or code, for open-source browsers, that would confirm that modern browsers index elements by class?

Comment: $("#id").find(".class"); should be even faster

Comment: well, in IE8 and below, there was no document.getElementsByClassName, so prior to IE9 it was faster to filter it more. in IE7 there also wasn't a querySelectorAll, so it was even worse. Obviously, as browsers were updated and improved their methods became more performant, the same with each jQuery version. At this point there's little to no reason to think about performance until you have a performance problem, instead take the more readable/maintainable route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have answered my own question. I created a jsperf, but I would value more test data or improvements.

http://jsperf.com/should-we-always-descend-by-an-id/6

EDIT: In my test case it looks like jQuery is actually faster when you DON'T descend from an id, but the clear performance winner (cross-browser) is **document.getElementsByClassName()**.

Comment: that test is likely flawed in that jQuery probably doesn't use querySelector for getting elements by className in modern browsers. (but the test using said method doesn't seem to want to run correctly in jsperf...)

Comment: and the previous comment also depends on jQuery version used (1.x vs 2.x/3.x)

Answer (score 1):

The difference in performance is there, but it may not be significant unless you're working with a very large markup.

I setup a benchmark JS Fiddle that creates 20,000 div tags each nested 10 levels deep.  Then attempts to select one at random based on class, and again based on ID with a descendant class.

I've benchmarked it here:  https://jsfiddle.net/0wyLfnz8/14/

**Results**
Selecting by ID then descendant class was on average .018ms in Chrome
Selecting by ID then descendant class was on average 39.33ms in IE

Selecting by class alone was on average 12.178ms in Chrome
Selecting by class alone was on average 51.386ms in IE

Again, those results are in milliseconds with 500 tests over 20,000 HTML elements

**Code for Benchmarking**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var st = d.getTime();
  var start = st;
  var et;
  var max = 20000;
  var numberOfTests = 500;
  var elementDepth = 10;
  for(var i = 1; i < max; i++) {
    //lets make a random class too
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var depth = "";
    for(var j = 1; j<elementDepth;j++) {
      depth += '<div class="depth' + j + '"></div>'
    }
    $('body').append('<div id="d'+i+'">'+depth+'<div class="depth'+elementDepth+'"><div class="c'+i+' r'+r+'">Hello, I am div number '+i+'</div></div></div>');
  }
  d = new Date();
  var duration = d.getTime() - st;
  console.log('Generating divs took ' + (duration/1000) + ' seconds');

  idDuration = 0;
  idTests = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
    //choose a random div to select
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    d = new Date();
    st = d.getTime();
    var tagbyID = $('#d'+r+ '.c'+r);
    d = new Date();
    et = d.getTime();
    duration =  et - st;


    //console.log('Selecting by ID took ' + duration + ' milliseconds');
    idDuration += duration;
    idTests++;
  }
  console.log('---');

  classDuration = 0;
  classTests = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) {
    //choose a random div to select
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
    d = new Date();
    st = d.getTime();
    var tagbyClass = $('.c'+r);
    d = new Date();
    et = et;
    duration = d.getTime() - st;
    //console.log('Selecting by class took ' + duration + ' milliseconds');
    classDuration += duration;
    classTests++;
  }
  console.log('---');
  d = new Date();
  console.log('total duration: ' + ((d.getTime() - start)/1000) + " seconds");
  console.log('---');
  console.log('Selecting by ID took '+idDuration+' milliseconds total over '+idTests+' tests.');
  console.log('Selecting by class took '+classDuration+' milliseconds total over '+classTests+' tests.');
  console.log('---');
  console.log('Average time for ID selection using $(\'#parentID .childClassName\') was: ' + (idDuration / idTests)+" milliseconds")
  console.log('Average time for class selection using $(\'.className\') was: ' + (classDuration / classTests)+" milliseconds")


})
```